# Showing there's no potential for a vector field on some region of the space?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, potential-theory

Imagining we have a vector field $f$ for which $\operatorname{curl} f = (0,0,0)$, why can there be a potential to it on some region and not on some other. e.g. what kind of reasoning can prove that there's no potential for $$f = \left( \frac{y}{x^2+y^2}, -\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}, 0 \right)$$ on the region $$R = \{ (x,y,z) : (x,y) \neq (0,0) \}?$$ Any hint or help would be greatly appreciated, I really don't see it. Thank you!

Why does $g=\arctan\left(\dfrac{x}{y}\right)-\dfrac{x+y}{x^2+y^2}$ not work?

Comment: The reason $\arctan(x/y)$ doesn't work is that it's not continuous.  The function approaches $0$ when we approach the positive $x$-axis from above, and $2\pi$ when we approach it from below.  (Not sure where the other piece came from, but it doesn't help matters.)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Integrate $f$ over the unit circle in the $xy$-plane.

Comment: Riiiight, non-zero, thank you!